# Pecl doesn't work in php:7.0-fpm image

Tags: php, docker, php-7

I have pretty simple dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get clean \
    && apt-get update && pecl install memeched
```

But unfortunately I am getting error:

```
pecl/memcached requires PHP (version >= 5.2.0, version <= 6.0.0, excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is 7.0.12
```

Why is that?

Comment: See if this helps - https://talk.plesk.com/threads/php7-and-memcached-again.337331/

Comment: I ended up using ubuntu:16 image and installing memached as php-memcached package